# php & mysql: configuration with a twist

Tags: php, mysql, configuration

I have a bit of an interesting problem concerning the configuration of php and mysql. I cannot configure them to work together. Whenever try to connect to a mysql database, I get the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql connect( ) .

I am currently using the latest version of mysql and php and am using a Windows 7 box as the server.

Due to certain restrictions, I cannot use a prefigured web server or package (no xampp, apache or easyphp). Therefore, I am pretty much restricted to using the built-in development server that comes with php. So far, I have done the editing to the php.ini file, removed the semicolon from php_mysql.dll to remove the ; and changed extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext" to reflect my extension folder.

I guess the two questions I have are:

A) can the php 5.4 included development server even connect to a mysql database

B) if so, can anyone provide me with some possible fixes to this configuration problem?

Any help given is appreciated.

-

Comment: You should probably post your code

Comment: Also, `mysql_connect()` is deprecated, so you shouldn't be using it anyway. As the documentation says on a huge red warning notice: "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."

Comment: Did you restart the dev server after enabling the extension in your php.ini file?

Comment: @ Keith: yes, I restarted my development server.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `phpinfo();` and see if you have configured it to work with MySQL.

Comment: It seems as though my extensions are not configuring properly. I have removed the semicolons to activate the extensions, but after running a code to see which ones are activated in php, none of the ones I have "activated" show up. I used:

Comment: <?php // extensions_list.php 

$list = get_loaded_extensions(); 
$list2 = array_map('strtolower',$list); 
sort($list2); 
echo '<pre>'.print_r($list2,true).'</pre>'; 

?>

Comment: [0] => bcmath
    [1] => calendar
    [2] => cli_server
    [3] => core
    [4] => ctype
    [5] => date
    [6] => dom
    [7] => ereg
    [8] => filter
    [9] => ftp
    [10] => hash
    [11] => iconv
    [12] => json
    [13] => libxml
    [14] => mcrypt
    [15] => mhash
    [16] => mysqlnd
    [17] => odbc
    [18] => pcre
    [19] => pdo
    [20] => phar
    [21] => reflection
    [22] => session
    [23] => simplexml
    [24] => spl
    [25] => standard
    [26] => tokenizer
    [27] => wddx
    [28] => xml
    [29] => xmlreader
    [30] => xmlwriter
    [31] => zip
    [32] => zlib

Answer (score -1):

You should enable php_mysql module from php.ini. Default is disabled.

From php.ini:

```
...
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
...
```

Remove `;` from the corresponding module, save and restart apache.

Comment: I cannot use a web server for this project. No apache, Xampp, or easyphp. I am using the php development server included within php 5.4.

Comment: also, I did just that, but php is still not picking up the activated extensions.

Comment: you don't mention mysql version. You probably have a bad mysql lib inside your php distribution. Probably php is giving some error when loading php library and you should enable startup errors to detect what happens.

Comment: Check in your php.ini file for `display_startup_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`